# using sox files in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, sox

I wanna make c++ app for audio with QT, and I wanna use `sox`, I import src folder of sox.sourceforg.net project code. and type very simple code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <src/sox.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    sox_format_t* input = sox_open_read("d.wav", NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

but encounter error for `undefined reference to sox_open_read'`. since this function with autocomplete show while I programmed.

I have a lot of search in this site and github and find these below links, but did not fix my prb

[Recording using sox in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825858/recording-using-sox-in-c-c)

[Android NDK linking problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582765/android-ndk-linking-problems)

[How can I send my audio file to stdout with the libsox library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787723/how-can-i-send-my-audio-file-to-stdout-with-the-libsox-library)

[Reducing a channel from wav file using libsox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141679/reducing-a-channel-from-wav-file-using-libsox/17173018#17173018)

[How can i determine duration of wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936113/how-can-i-determine-duration-of-wav-file/56941112#56941112)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add error message. If error is concerning linker (LNK...) than you didn't link sox library into application.

Comment: C:\Users\SATSom\Documents\Qt Project 1\build-resample-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\..\resample\mainwindow.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `sox_open_read'
debug/mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
C:\Users\SATSom\Documents\Qt Project 1\build-resample-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/../resample/mainwindow.cpp:12: undefined reference to `sox_open_read'

Comment: Ok slightly strange. Try to wrap src/sox.h with extern-c: use (separated to lines) ```extern "C" { #include <src/sox.h> }```

Comment: thx, but this prb is still with same error ;(

Comment: So do you actually link against the library? Did you add it in your pro-file (when you use qmake)?

Comment: Absolutely these are the first work of any prjs